# Bookdown generates index file with a chapter title instead of "index.html" when knitted

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I am compiling a long report into a html document with Bookdown and didn't have any problems knitting it with bookdown::gitbook until recently. Not sure what happened.

The code runs without errors, all the plots and files are generated as needed, but the index.rmd is generated into an .html file named after the first heading's id ("chapter00.html"), rather than "index.html". This means it the website does not work when uploaded to github.

Everything works great if the file name is manually changed to "index.html".

My index.rmd file looks as follows:

```
--- 
title: "Eesti inimarengu aruanne 2019"
author: "Eesti Koostöö Kogu"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [bibliography/bib_chapter23.bib, bibliography/bib_chapterXY.bib]
biblio-style: authoryear
biblatexoptions: [refsegment=chapter]
csl: keel-ja-kirjandus.csl
link-citations: yes
description: "Eesti inimarengu aruanne 2019"
css: eia.css
lang: et
---

# Sissejuhatus {-#chapter00 .chapter_section .intro_section}
```

_bookdown.yml file is as follows:

```
book_filename: "EIA_2019_digi"
language:
  label:
    fig: 'Joonis '
    tab: 'Tabel '
    eq: 'Valem '
  ui:
    chapter_name: ""
delete_merged_file: true
```

_output.yml is as follows:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_by: section
  split_bib: yes
  config:
    toc:
      collapse: subsection
      scroll_highlight: yes
      before: null
      after: null
      toolbar:
      position: fixed
      edit : null
      download: null
      search: yes
    sharing:
      facebook: no
      twitter: no
      google: no
      linkedin: no
      weibo: no
      instapaper: no
      vk: no
      all: ['facebook', 'google', 'twitter', 'linkedin', 'weibo', 'instapaper']
bookdown::pdf_book:
  includes:
    in_header: preamble.tex
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
bookdown::epub_book: default
```

Any insight about what may cause the problem? Thanks!

Comment: hi could it be that `# Sissejuhatus {-#chapter00 .chapter_section .intro_section}` shouldnt be in the index.rmd?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply!

I don't think this is the problem as you should be able to add content to the index file. There is content in the Bookdown demo file available here: [link](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo)

Comment: hi,did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey! No, I haven't as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are *knitting* your bookdown project, when you should render it with bookdown. In the R console:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd")
```

Check the last line of your output is something like

```
Output created: docs/index.html
[1] "/my/path/mybook/docs/index.html"
```

That should generate an index.html file from your index.rmd file

(And remember to set Source **master branch/docs folder** under Settings > Github Pages if you are using github.io to publish)

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced this problem, and I can actually reproduce it in a particular way, which doesn't appear to be exactly the same as yours. If I **don't** keep any actual content or a markdown header in the `index.Rmd` file, then the rendered HTML file is named after the first header in the next Rmd file. If I put just one header in the `index.Rmd` file, then it renders to index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in a project where I included chapters written in .md files using this approach:

in `_bookdown.yml`:

```
book_filename: "PGDEPhysics"
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: ""
    appendix_name: "Appendix "
delete_merged_file: true
output_dir: "docs"

rmd_files: [
  'index.Rmd'
  ,'content.Rmd'
  ,'appendix.Rmd'
  ,'bibliography.Rmd'
]
```

the file `content.Rmd`:

````
```{r content, echo=FALSE}
library(fs)
cvec = dir_ls("Content", regexp = "^(.+).md$")
```
```{r child = cvec}
```
````

If the first file in the `Content` folder begins with a top-level heading:

```
# The first chapter
```

Everything is fine, and bookdown outputs an `index.html` file as required. If that first heading the first file starts with a subheading:

```
## The first chapter
```

Then we see this in the output:

```
Output created: docs/welcome.html
```

instead of the required:

```
Output created: docs/index.html
```

('Welcome' is the first top-level heading in `index.Rmd`)

Solution for me is to just live with it, and have that first .md file begin with a top-level heading.

The difficulty with this feature is that the problem is not noticed at the point it is introduced unless you are clearing out the target folder (in my case, `docs`) each time you build the book, because an older version of `index.html` may remain there and the site looks fine during development. The build process only adds files, it doesn't delete them from the target folder.

Best practice workflow, then, is to delete the target folder before you build.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well when including `index.Rmd` from a location not in the project directory. Moving the file fixed the naming problem.

For instance, I originally had the file in a subdirectory (e.g., `doc/index.Rmd`) and included this in `_bookdown.yml`: `rmd_files: ["doc/index.Rmd", "doc/introduction.Rmd"]`. This led to the output file being `introduction.html`.

Moving `index.Rmd` to the root directory and using `rmd_files: ["index.Rmd"]` led to the output file being `index.html`.

Note that it seems that removing `index.Rmd` from `_bookdown.yml` (i.e., `rmd_files: ["doc/introduction.Rmd"]`), also leads to an output of `introduction.html`.

Answer (score 0):

It also can happen if the first chapter (`index.Rmd`) has more than one level one header (`#`)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have *one* yaml header. If you have more then one, than the last one overwrites the main title.

See: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-project.html#bookdown-project